# How do you type `\` inside a codeblock in chat?

Tags: support, chat, markdown, code-formatting

I showed someone in the Bridge how to make a shrug emoji (¯\_(ツ)_/¯) and while discussing the use of backticks, code blocks and backslashes in markdown, I realized that it's impossible to type backtick backslash backtick in a code block in chat, or if there is a way, I haven't figured it out yet. I've tried a bunch of things in [the sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47409455#47409455), but I can't get it to work.

What I want to achieve is `` `\` ``, but in a chat message. However, when I type  ``` `` `\` `` ``` in chat, it tries to render it a couple times and then doesn't render what I hoped it would.

How can I make `` `\` `` appear in chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
``​`\`​``
```

([proof](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51845727) - that's really an inline code block, see below)

This string is composed of two backticks, a [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), `` `\` ``, another zero width space, and again two backticks. So basically what you already had, but with zero width spaces instead of regular ones. There might be easier ways, though ...

[image]

Comment: yeah, I'm hoping for an easier way that does not involve inserting random Unicode characters in the message.